# CardboardSDK conflict (duplicate symbol) in google protobuf library

Tags: ios, dependency-management, google-cardboard, protocol-buffers, google-vr

I've successfully integrated and configured my CardboardSDK project in a test project, now I want to integrate it in my main project which already uses GTL library for YouTube uploading and in this new project I'm getting 641 duplicate symbols for classes with strange names.

**What I've tried:**

I've addressed some conflicts with GoogleAdMob and GoogleConversion SDKs.
I've addressed conflicts for all the cases where I could find a relevant class name somewhere else in the project, like AFNetworking, OAuth etc.

But still there are 641 duplicate symbols.

```
duplicate symbol __ZN6google8protobuf8internal20InitLogSilencerCountEv in:
    /Users/sabirali/Documents/4.2.1/libCardboardSDK.a(common.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN6google8protobuf8internal22DeleteLogSilencerCountEv in:
    /Users/sabirali/Documents/4.2.1/libCardboardSDK.a(common.o)

...
...

duplicate symbol __ZN6google8protobuf2io18StringOutputStreamC1EPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/sabirali/Documents/4.2.1/libCardboardSDK.a(zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN6google8protobuf2io22LazyStringOutputStreamC2EPNS0_14ResultCallbackIPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEEEE in:
    /Users/sabirali/Documents/4.2.1/libCardboardSDK.a(zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN6google8protobuf2io22LazyStringOutputStreamC1EPNS0_14ResultCallbackIPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEEEE in:
    /Users/sabirali/Documents/4.2.1/libCardboardSDK.a(zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.o)
ld: 641 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Problem:**

1. I'm unable to fully understand where these duplicate symbols are coming from, my calculated guess is its fro m GTL SDK by google but I do need that for YouTube uploading and can't remove it. e.g. Is this class name `__ZN6google8protobuf8internal20InitLogSilencerCountEv` randomly generated ?
2. How can I find out exactly which SDK / Framework in my project is indirectly using the same google library which Cardboard SDK is using ?
3. I would even like to explicitly silence the duplicate symbols, using some compiler flags, if possible ?

**UPDATE:**

1. I found out that the issue is not with the YouTube API, as Ive removed that API and all other google SDKs from my project and am still getting the conflict.
2. I've checked the object files inside the SDK and its not them, its `protobuf` library internally being used by some of the classed inside Cardboard SDK.
3. How can I find out which library is having `protobuf` as a dependancy ?